# Imread & argv image location?

Tags: c++, opencv, argv

I am new to coding in C++ and am currently working on an application that can clear all objects out of a picture except for the biggest one. I was looking on doing object size detection based on the bounding boxes tutorial I found [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rects_circles/bounding_rects_circles.html)

But this code contains one line using the imread function and then an array to specify the path to the image

```
/// Load source image and convert it to gray
src = imread( argv[1], 1 );
```

How is it that argv[1] can be used in this situation to point out where the image is sourced from? I thought argv & argc had to do with the number of command lines that are called? Any information?

As stated earlier I am new to c++ so sorry if this is a silly question.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`argc` contains number of command line arguments, wheren `argv` contains the commands themselves, where the first command is the *program name itself*. For example:

```
./program param1 param2
```

will have `argc=3`  and

```
argv[0] = program
argv[1] = param1
argv[2] = param2
```

so if your program name is `program` and your file path is `D:/folder/file`
then you should replace `param1` with `D:/folder/file` and then `argv[1]` will contain the file path.

Comment: How do I add in those commands before executing the program itself then? Cmd only pops up right after debugging..

Comment: @TheAlPaca02: this is no longer a C++ problem, but an environment problem. From your question you are probably using a code editor (such as Visual Studio) to develop your C++ program, and launching the program from your editor, I advise to check on SO how to add a command line in your particular editor (and if you cannot find it, ask a new question precising exactly which editor you use).

Comment: @TheAlPaca02, as Matthieu pointed out, search using the specific IDE you are using how can you set arguments. For Visual Studio, right click on the project, select properties and in the dialog, you will find an option *Command Arguments* where you can set them. Note: You don't need to specify the program name in case of using IDE.

Answer (score 0):

You may find the info on argc, argv [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024197/what-does-int-argc-char-argv-mean). So **yes**, `imread` can take one of the parameters in `argv` as a string which specifies the image file name/path.